# Dependency property in user control doesn't have any effect

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls

In my user control (class *LabeledBox*), I've added dependency property as follows.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalProperty 
  = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Horizontal", 
    typeof (Orientation), 
    typeof (LabeledBox), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default(Orientation)));

public Orientation Horizontal
{
  get { return (Orientation) GetValue(HorizontalProperty); }
  set { SetValue(HorizontalProperty, value); }
}
```

However, when setting it according to the below, doesn't give me any difference in behavior. In fact, the setter in the property doesn't get called. What do I miss?

```
<local:LabeledBox x:Name="Info field" 
                  Description="Info" 
                  Horizontal="Horizontal" />
```

The component in question has a stack panel as outermost control and it's bound like this.

```
<StackPanel Name="TheContainer" Orientation="{Binding Horizontal}">
```

Perhaps I've done the binding incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a name to your `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl .... x:Name="labeledBox">
```

And use the binding like this:

```
<StackPanel Name="TheContainer" Orientation="{Binding Horizontal, ElementName=labeledBox}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes your `Binding` is not well try to update it to be seems like:

```
<StackPanel Name="TheContainer" 
            Orientation="{
              Binding Horizontal,
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:LabeledBox}}"/>
```